# Error: "-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector" while executing the core plot in iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-plot

I get the below error when I try to compile the below code:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6768c10'

Code:

```
 UIView *ChartView;

  ChartView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: ChartView.bounds];

CPGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPGraphHostingView *)ChartView;
hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're casting a `UIView` instance (which does *not* respond to `-setHostedGraph:`) to a `CPGraphHostingView`. - This will **not** work.

You'll need to create an actual `CPGraphHostingView` object, *then* invoke `-setHostedGraph:` on it.

So, your code should look like this:

```
CGRect someFrame = ...;
CPGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: hostingView.bounds];

hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
```

Comment: If I dont use UIView then how will it determine which UIView is the hostView for this core plot? I have four Views on my ViewController. So what can be done in that case?