# CorePlot SIGABRT runtime error xcode4

Tags: xcode4, core-plot

I've modified the code at http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application to run on xcode4, I have a view that I put into my ConsoleViewControllor.xib with its class as CPTGraphHostingView.

Compiles great, at runtime however, I get a SIGABRT at line
 hostingView.hostedGraph = graph; with the error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setHostedGraph:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5910d40'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Anyone else run into this issue? I'm more than willing to give you code and answer more questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the setup in your .xib again. **-[UIView setHostedGraph:]** means that Xcode created a `UIView`, not a `CPTGraphHostingView`.

Comment: This solved my problem completely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038539/error-uiview-sethostedgraph-unrecognized-selector-while-executing-the-cor